# How to apply .presentationBackground modifier to a second view in a sheet with NavigationLink?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-sheet

Been searching around online for a while and can't seem to find an answer to help me with this problem, since the .presentationBackground modifier is so new.

**Problem:**

When applying the .presentationBackground modifier to a presented sheet, **the modifer does not get applied to the second view** that's presented via a NavigationLink on the presented sheet. The first view that's presented as the sheet has the material background, but the second view from the NavigationLink has a solid white background.

**Context:**

*Running the simulator on iPhone 14 with iOS 16.4 and Xcode 14.3*

I currently have a view with a button that presents a sheet:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State private var showingAddItemSheet = false
    
    @available(iOS 16.4, *)
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    showingAddItemSheet.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .font(Font.system(size: 32, weight: .semibold))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddItemSheet) {
                    AddItemView(isPresented: $showingAddItemSheet)
                        .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.6)])
                        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
                        .presentationBackground(.ultraThinMaterial)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.green)
        }
    }
}
```

The sheet contains a NavigationLink to a second view:

```
struct AddItemView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State private var itemName: String = ""
    
    @State private var itemDetails: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Add Item")
                
                TextField("Name", text: $itemName)
                
                NavigationLink("Add Item Details") {
                    AddItemDetailsView(itemDetails: $itemDetails)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second view does not maintain the .presentationBackground modifier from the initial sheet, but it does maintain the .presentationDetents and .presentationDragIndicator.

```
struct AddItemDetailsView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @Binding var itemDetails: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Add Item Details")
            
            TextField("Details", text: $itemDetails)
            
            Button("Done") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried:**

None of the following have worked to get the .presentationBackground(.ultraThinMaterial) to apply to the second view :

- Adding the .presentationBackground modifier to the AddItemDetailsView() in the NavigationLink destination
- Setting the .background of the AddItemDetailsView to Color.clear or to .ultraThinMaterial directly with the regular .background modifier.
- Changing the NavigationView on the AddItemView to a NavigationStack

Would greatly appreciate any ideas or guidance here on how to get the second AddItemDetailsView to use the .ultraThinMaterial background like the first AddItemView sheet!

Answer (score 0):

I played with it a little, and to my understanding, a `NavigationLink` does not have the same capabilities as a `Sheet` and vice versa. So instead of using a `NavigationLink`, you could use another `Sheet`, but the view hierarchy does **NOT** make it the same material, because it will be in front of another `Sheet`.

```
struct AddItemView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State private var itemName: String = ""
    
    @State private var itemDetails: String = ""
    
    @State private var showingAddItemSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Add Item")
                
                TextField("Name", text: $itemName)
                
                Button {
                    showingAddItemSheet.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Item Details")
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddItemSheet) {
                AddItemDetailsView(itemDetails: $itemDetails)
                    .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.6)])
                    .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
                    .presentationBackground(.ultraThinMaterial)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you would pull the AddItemView sheet to the top, you will see a small difference in the material, but as I said, a Sheet on top of a Sheet with both having the modifier, just makes it a bit darker, because it looks onto the other Sheet.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look - I really appreciate it! Would you happen to know if there's another way to present a second view in a sheet while preserving the sheet capabilities? I'd love to maintain the horizontal sliding in of a second view in a sheet without having to add another sheet on top, but that's definitely a good option!

Comment: You could look into his second code answer and change it to your needs. It basically works with animations and transitions to achieve your desired output. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571403/13597528